# Strong parameters with Sinatra?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, sinatra, strong-parameters

Can I use [strong_params](https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters) in a Sinatra project? Are there any Sinatra option for the same?

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried [Sinatra Param](https://github.com/mattt/sinatra-param) by Mattt Thompson? It's implementation is slightly different, but the result is similar to what strong params does for Rails.

As per documentation example:

```
# GET /search?q=example
# GET /search?q=example&categories=news
# GET /search?q=example&sort=created_at&order=ASC
get '/search' do
   param :q,           String, required: true
   param :categories,  Array
   param :sort,        String, default: "title"
   param :order,       String, in: ["ASC", "DESC"], transform: :upcase, default: "ASC"
   param :price,       String, format: "[<\=>]\s*\$\d+"

   {...}.to_json
 end
```